# Form will not submit with captcha

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, submit, captcha

I have used this as a starting point for a form on my website that needs a captcha, however upon adding it, it does not submit to the action.php page to move on the user.

What can I do so that it will submit?

http://jsfiddle.net/swade/M5rvh/

```
<form id="form" action="action.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />

    <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>

$(function(){

    var mathenticate = {
        bounds: {
            lower: 5,
            upper: 50
        },
        first: 0,
        second: 0,
        generate: function()
        {
            this.first = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.bounds.lower) + 1;
            this.second = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.bounds.upper) + 1;
        },
        show: function()
        {
            return this.first + ' + ' + this.second;
        },
        solve: function()
        {
            return this.first + this.second;
        }
    };
    mathenticate.generate();

    var $auth = $('<input type="text" name="auth" />');
    $auth
        .attr('placeholder', mathenticate.show())
        .insertAfter('input[name="name"]');

    $('#form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if( $auth.val() != mathenticate.solve() )
        {
            alert('wrong answer!');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The default action would be the form submit which you are always preventing. 
Only prevent it, if your captcha doesn't match.

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    if( $auth.val() != mathenticate.solve() )
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('wrong answer!');
    }
});
```

Comment: I thought the name would give it away. Anyway, you are preventing the default action with this line: `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: I have tried taking that line out but then it moves the user onto the next page even if the captcha is wrong

Comment: You might want to read the code block in my answer. It's preventing the default action only if the captcha didn't match.